# Azure CDN Verizon Premium Hidden SAS token GET method Error 403

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cdn, azure-cdn

I have pretty simple question. 
Our company is using Azure CDN Premium Verizon (because of options of Rules Engine).
I have succesfully configured Endpoint with custom domain which is pointed to Origin Azure Blob Storage. 
In this blob storage we have some Containers secured as Private.
I have followed instructions on Microsoft website to configure Hidden SAS token Authentication with URL Rewrite Rule.
The CDN point called cdn.company.com is working pretty nice. The content stored in Private Blob Storage is view-able in any internet browser (Chrome, IE, Edge..) via CDN point and also with hidden SAS token Rule.
The problem is that our API of internet application is trying to call CDN endpoint via GET method. And thats it. Everytime an error 403 has been occured. I dont really know how to fix that.
I am attaching screenshot from rule engine down below.
Thank you for every ideas.

In screenshots I am trying to get content via GET method of some JavaScript stored in private container "jsc".

[image: GET method from Chrome Console]

[image: Rules Engine Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved... In the end it was problem with regex syntax. The second problem was that our API of the Internet Application generated a random pattern automatically. 
So I used regex like 
    /80XXXXX/XXXXXXX/([\w-.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w-]+)?$
and now everything works properly.